# Application is Stuck on Build/Run Process

Tags: c++, netbeans

I am using Netbeans 6.8 and trying to run a simple application, here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>


    int main()
    {
        std::cout<< "Game Over!" << std::endl; // Displays "Game Over" Output
        return 0;
    }
```

Netbeans says there are no errors and it cleans and builds just fine but when I click Build/Run it seems to get stuck. I literally went to the supermarket and returned to find that my program still hadn't run.

Any ideas on what the problem could be and how to fix it would be a big help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it's the program cause this. Try finding the executable and running in on the command line and seeing if it hangs.

Comment: I opened the executable like you suggested and it did work which means there is something wrong with the IDE because it won't run any of the programs, not even the sample apps it provides.

Any ideas on what the problem is? If not I suppose I can just open the executables directly and work around it. Thanks for the help. =)

Comment: No problem, sorry I've never used Netbeans before...not much help on that front heh.